# Modifying an array in Dafny with postconditions

Tags: dafny

Trying to implement a fairly simple method, where you pass an empty array and place values into it (natural numbers).

The code runs fine, but a simple postcondition that ought to pass in my mind is throwing me errors.

```
method Main() {
  var a := new int[5];
  initialise(a);

}

method initialise(a: array<int>) 
modifies a
requires a.Length > 0
ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < a.Length ==> a[i] == i
{
    var i := 0;
    while i < a.Length
    invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
    decreases  a.Length - i
  {
        a[i] := i;
        i := i + 1;
    }
}
```

Error:

`A postcondition might not hold on this return path. Related location 1: Line: 10, Col: 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Dafny about the invariant maintained by the loop.

Once you add

```
invariant forall j :: 0 <= j < i ==> a[j] == j
```

the proof goes through.

Comment: If you'd like, you can also leave out the precondition `a.Length > 0`, because your `initialise` method also works for an empty array.

Comment: Cheers for this! One question - I thought that the invariant needed to hold before the loop executes, in which case I wouldn't have thought it would verify correctly. Does the invariant only check after the loop has iterated through?

Comment: It has to hold before the loop, and it does. `i` is 0 before the loop so the antecedent of the implication is false and the implication is true for all `j`.